# True only on Weekdays and at a specific time

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using `PHP 7.4.1` and `Laravel Framework 6.20.12` with the `carbon` library.

I want to return `true` **only once** from Monday to Friday if a date crosses the `$sendPost` variable. My cron-job runs every `5 Minutes`.

I tried:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

function checkMsgFired() {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    // $now = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', "19/1/2021 14:43:00");

    $lastSendPost = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', "18/1/2021 14:43:00"); // the posting has already happended today

    $post = array();
    $post['Frequency'] = "MoToFr"; // send only from monday to friday at a specific date once
    $post['sendPost'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "14:40:00"); // when the post should be send


    if($post['Frequency'] === "MoToFr") {
        // if it is a WEEKDAY
        if($now->dayOfWeek !== Carbon::SATURDAY or $now->dayOfWeek !== Carbon::SUNDAY) {
            // $lastPosting didn't happen today
            if(!$lastSendPost->isToday() && $now->gt($post['sendPost'])){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


var_dump(checkMsgFired());
```

However, the posting time does not seem to work. How can I check that the event has already fired **once** at the exact time?

Furthermore, is there an easier version to code this?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You’ll likely need to store whether or not it has been sent in the database or other storage for this to be reliable. Cron jobs don’t always run to the second, so you may find that it’s enough to trip you up if you’re looking for a window of time. It might be easier to create a span of time and see if the time now is within that span if you want to keep this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like possibly? This’ll give you true when the time is between 14:40 and 14:45, so long as your cron job runs every 5 minutes it *should* be mostly correct.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

function checkMsgFired() {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $frequency = "MoToFr";
    $sendPost = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "14:40:00");

    if ($frequency === "MoToFr") {
        if ($now->isWeekday()) {
            return $now->between($sendPost, $sendPost->addMinutes(5));
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(checkMsgFired());
```

Comment: Thx! If I only use `->addMinutes(4)` am I on the save side then?

Comment: That danger with using `4` would be that if it was triggered a fraction out and occurred at 14:39:58 or something, then there could be a gap on the other side. I would stick with `5` and see how it fares with your server setup.

Comment: And here you also can have duplicated/missed, because the script itself takes a few microseconds "now" will not be exactly 5 minutes after previous cron job. So you should use `now < $sendPost + 5 minutes` and `not sent` (with no minimum bound), then once it's sent, flag a "sent" boolean in your DB to not re-send it on next occurrence.

Comment: Yeah if you can store whether or not it’s sent, you can basically get rid of most of this script and just ask “has it been sent today?” which is much easier.